# wcf - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: wcf

I created a WCF service.  It worked well yesterday.  When I entered service address, I got message returned as expected.  However, when I run it today, I received error message:
In IE: [Fiddler] The socket connection to localhost failed. 
ErrorCode: 10061. No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it [::1]:47423 
In Firefox: Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at the site
In Fiddle2: HTTP: 502
How to solve this problem?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally with these issues is either the service is not running or you're url is incorrect.  Without more specific information it's impossible to tell.

Comment: Chawk: Thanks for your feedback.  I re-checked the URL and then got correct return in both IE and Firefox.  Thanks.